# Rigging Functionality - Can I use Blender to automatically create a set of poses from a T-pose?

Tags: mesh, rigging, pose-mode

I appreciate I need to learn a lot but before I dive in I'd like some guidance on what direction to start looking.

I sculpt 28mm scale wargaming miniatures in Zbrush and then manually pose a basic T- rig to make a bunch of different poses (walking forward, running etc) - its very tedious and time consuming.

I understand I can set up a bone armature, parent a bunch of objects then use the bone to pose a bunch of figures.

Now my main question - lets say I create a new set of components with different design elements - armour, boots, fabric etc - Is there a way to parent the new components to a Bone rig, such that with a few clicks, I can automatically move the new components to all the same poses as the previous set, without having to manually reposition the bones again?

I am thinking perhaps there is a way to use animation to move the bone rig to a series of pre determined poses, having first connected the mesh objects.

If someone is an expert in using blender for bone rigging like this, and thinks they might have a workable solution, I am happy to PAY to be walked through it over discord :slight_smile:

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Joel